# Валидация с регулярным выражением

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, asp.net

У меня на полях есть валидация и мне нужно вникнуть как она делается что бы переделать какие то моменты под себя. Вот моя регулярка.

```
^\d{1,}$|^$"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что она в себе несёт. И если не сложно приведите пример на регулярку которая даёт вводить только цифры и тире обычное и на регулярку которая даёт вводить цифры и английский и русский алфавиты обоих регистров. Или хотя бы объясните как это сделать.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ Вставьте сюда ваш код и справа отобразиться его описание на английском.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `^\d{1,}$|^$"`

Строка, подходящая под такое регулярное выражение, не должна содержать ничего кроме цифр. Пустая строка допускается. В принципе, можно записать и короче — `^\d*$`.

> приведите пример, регулярки которая даёт вводить только цифры и тире обычное

`^[\d-]*$` — разрешает только комбинацию цифр или [дефисоминусов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81#.D0.94.D0.B5.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.81_.D0.B8_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BF.D1.8C.D1.8E.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B). Обратите внимание, что этот минус стоит прямо у самого квадратной скобочки, чтобы он не был воспринят как указание непрерывного диапазона.

> приведите пример регулярки, которая даёт вводить цифры и английский и русский алфавиты обоих регистров

`^[0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]*$` — букву Ё приходится указывать отдельно, т.к. в таблице юникода она находится вне основного ряда русских букв.

---

Помните, вы всегда можете ознакомиться с краткой справкой по регулярным выражениям в [нашем описании метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info).